# Why are the page elements, animation, parallax loading so choppy?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, html, animation

I have been searching for the answer for hours now, and finally decided to get some help from the community.

I can't figure out why this site is loading so choppy. The animation is bad, the parallax is bad, and when you scroll everything loads in parts.

Any direction or advice on this would be greatly appreciated.

http://tinyurl.com/hef2k27

Answer (score 1):

There is sooo much to cover in website optimisation. At first glance, your website takes **6.4mb to load**, this is huge. You have few images that are over 1mb and this is a no-no in web developement, try saving them as a jpeg with 60% quality. This should helps a bit.

As far as script performance goes, did you code everything yourself? If so, you'll need to dive in your code and optimize it in every way possible.

Optimizing website is a job on it's own, There is just so much that we can do on stackoverflow.

**EDIT**

You put transition:0s; on your class .parallaximg, try removing the transition by replacing it with `transition:none`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and analysis, Kirgan and Xposedbones.. I did not code this, so trying to figure it out. Looks like I have good places to start by reducing file sizes.

Answer (score 1):

in chrome you can check under tab "Network" under the developper tool, open it and then reload your page (clear your cache before) and see the result.
You load more than 7MB of data, that's very huge.
First I'll optimize your images, prefere JPG instead of PNG format if you don't need transparency.
You can minimify your files, this may not be perfect but you will be able to see the difference

Hope it helps.